# Mystery space created above row when removing the content inside of one item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexbox

I have a grid with some items, and when I click any item I move the content of that item to a modal.

The modal works great, but when I remove the content from the item, a space appears above the item.

I know that a way around this problem could be using a flexbox, which works fine, but I want to understand what is going on here.

Something that could be key here is that each item has 3 children.

I use `position: absolute` in two of them, and the other one stays with the default position.

If I use `position: absolute` in all the children, the problem is fixed.

What is the difference?

When I click the item the content disappears, so how can the result be different depending on the content?

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dangonrei/67w721zq/) showing the problem.

Basically, the structure is the following:

#### HTML

```
<div class="context">
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="item">
            <div class="cover">  // has position: absolute
                <h1>Title</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="img-wrapper">  // has position: absolute
                <img/>
            </div>
            <div class="description">  // doesn't have a position defined
                <p>Description...</p>
            </div>
        <div class="item">
            // item content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have a total of 8 items, that are wrapped in two rows of 4 items each.

#### CSS

The CSS to achieve that is the following:

```
.grid {
  margin-top: 100px;
  font-size: 0; // to get all the items together
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.item {
  width: calc(100% / 4);
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.description {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.img-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

.cover {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

**Note**: The JSfiddle example has more CSS for styling, but the base is the same, and the problem still appears with the code above.

#### JavaScript

Finally, the JS to move the content to the modal div is the following:

```
let $itemNode;
let $itemContent;

$().ready(args => {
  // Cache the modal node
  let $modal = $('#modal');

  $('.item').click(function() {
    // First cache the item and content
    // to put it back when needed
    $itemNode = $(this);
    $itemContent = $(this).children();

    // Hides the item
    $itemNode.css({visibility: 'hidden'});

    // Transfer project content to the modal
    $itemContent.appendTo($modal);
  });

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solutions

> I know that a way around this problem could be using a flexbox...

That is correct. Making the parent of the items a flex container solves the problem:

```
.grid {
  display: flex;     /* new */
  flex-wrap: wrap;   /* new */
  margin-top: 100px;
  font-size: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

[revised fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/67w721zq/2/)

> Something that could be key here is that each item has 3 children. I use `position: absolute` in two of them, and the other one stays with the default position. If I use `position: absolute` in all the children, the problem is fixed.

Also, correct. By removing the third div from the normal flow of the document, the problem is resolved.

### Explanation

Each item in the grid, before any scripting gets involved and items are removed, is artificially positioned.

In other words, in their initial state, the content of the items (the three child divs) are shifting each item to a place where they would otherwise not be. But when the script removes those child divs, each item moves to where it should be.

As you suspected, the problem lies in the third child div of each grid item (`.description`).

If you simply apply `visibility: hidden` to the grid item – *without removing the child divs* – the layout doesn't break.

But with your script, you're not only adding `visibility: hidden`, you're also removing the child divs.

The first two divs (`.cover` and `.img-wrapper`) never cause a problem. They are absolutely positioned, so they're already removed from the normal flow.

However, the third div (`.description`) is an in-flow child.

This div contains two `p` children ("Description for this item X" and "More info"). When either of these children is removed, *that's when layout breaks*.

This is because – for a reason I haven't yet determined – this div was suppressing `vertical-align: baseline` on the parent, which is an inline-level element and, therefore, [gets that `vertical-align` setting by default](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#line-height).

When the script removes the div, baseline alignment is restored to the parent, shifting it up and, therefore, creating the gap.

---

EDIT:

As [@Kukkuz mentioned an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39794921/3597276), using values other than `baseline` for `vertical-align` also solves the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. After reading your answer and how removing the `p` elements created the *mystery space*, I've been playing with the structure and things are getting very weird. Look at this [new fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dangonrei/sa0psbtv/), where I placed a different amount of `p` tags inside each item

Comment: You're welcome. The new behavior is due to `justify-content: space-around` on the parent (`.description`). Just remove that rule or switch to `flex-start`. https://jsfiddle.net/sa0psbtv/2/

Comment: Wow, maybe this should be a different question, but how is the `space-around` moving the `.items` when all the `.descriptions` have the same dimensions?

Comment: Will have to study that. Only `space-around` is having that effect. All other values of `justify-content` keep the layout intact.

Answer (score 3):

Use `vertical-align: top` to `item` and you can get rid of the *mystery space* when the contents of any item is empty. This happens because the `grid` items are `inline` (inline-flex).

> Note that
>   `vertical-align` applies to all *inline-level* and *table-cell*
>   elements and is used to vertically align inline level elements- see
>   the doc
>   [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align).

*Change `inline-flex` to `inline-block` and you can see about the same behavior.* Toggle `vertical-align` in the below snippet and check for yourself:

```css
.context {
  text-align: center;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#modal {
  display: none
}
.grid {
  margin-top: 100px;
  font-size: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.item {
  width: calc(100% / 4);
  height: 100px;
  transform-origin: center;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  transition: box-shadow .3s, transform .3s;
  font-size: 1em;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.description {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: opacity .3s;
}
.img-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: white;
}
img {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
.cover {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  transition: transform .3s, opacity .3s;
}
.cover-red {
  background-color: #ff9f80;
}
.cover-green {
  background-color: #66cc66;
}
.cover-blue {
  background-color: #809fff;
}
.cover-yellow {
  background-color: #ffff80;
}
.cover-mag {
  background-color: hsl(338, 95%, 70%);
}
.cover-cyan {
  background-color: hsl(214, 100%, 65%);
}
.item:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  z-index: 1100;
  transform: scale(1.02);
}
.item:hover .cover {
  opacity: 0
}
```

```html
<div class="context">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="item">


    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <div class="cover cover-cyan">
        <h1>Title 2</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="img-wrapper">
        <img src="http://rs415.pbsrc.com/albums/pp236/Keefers_/Keffers%20Animals/funny-cats-a10.jpg~c200">
      </div>
      <div class="description">
        <p>Description for item 2</p>
        <p>More info</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <div class="cover cover-mag">
        <h1>Title 3</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="img-wrapper">
        <img src="http://i1.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/original/000/007/203/nononocat.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="description">
        <p>Description for item 3</p>
        <p>More info</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <div class="cover cover-green">
        <h1>Title 4</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="img-wrapper">
        <img src="https://media0.giphy.com/media/3o85xoi6nNqJQJ95Qc/200_s.gif">
      </div>
      <div class="description">
        <p>Description for item 4</p>
        <p>More info</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <div class="cover cover-cyan">
        <h1>Title 5</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="img-wrapper">
        <img src="https://media0.giphy.com/media/o0vwzuFwCGAFO/200_s.gif">
      </div>
      <div class="description">
        <p>Description for item 5</p>
        <p>More info</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <div class="cover cover-green">
        <h1>Title 6</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="img-wrapper">
        <img src="http://cdn.thecatsite.com/3/37/200x200px-ZC-379ffbad_anime-cat-cute-cuteness-overload-kitten-Favim_com-350157_large.jpeg">
      </div>
      <div class="description">
        <p>Description for item 6</p>
        <p>More info</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <div class="cover cover-red">
        <h1>Title 7</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="img-wrapper">
        <img src="http://www.officialstarwarscostumes.com/~/media/products/oc/yoda-costumes/pet-yoda-costumes/9935319-yoda-cat-hood-pet-star-wars-costumes-000.ashx?w=200&h=200&bc=ffffff">
      </div>
      <div class="description">
        <p>Description for item 7</p>
        <p>More info</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <div class="cover cover-mag">
        <h1>Title 8</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="img-wrapper">
        <img src="http://adst.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/cat-general-120-3-_tplq-200x200.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="description">
        <p>Description for item 8</p>
        <p>More info</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="modal">
  </div>
</div>
```

---

I created a demo with `inline-block` showing the same behavior. This is a general behavior of inline elements - see below:

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid;
}
.wrapper > * {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div></div>
  <div>
    <h1>kjk</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @DanielG.Reina have added explanation to the answer... let me know your feedback on this. Thanks!

Comment: thank you for your answer. That could be another solution to avoid the *mystery space* issue. By the way, the example runnable at your answer is not working, as if it wasn't executing any JS.However, my concern is, why is this happening? I've seen that `vertical-align` defaults to `baseline`, but I don't see why an empty item would be differently aligned. Furthermore, the problem is also gone if I use `vertical-align: bottom` or `vertical-align: middle`

Comment: yes, specifying `vertical-align` along the line-box (using `top` , `bottom` or `middle` solves the problem....

Comment: nice work.. i think `vertical-align` (your answer) or making the grid parent a flex container (my answer) are both good solutions..

Comment: @Michael_B thanks, I'm always learning from your solutions in SO :)

Comment: Thanks. But the question still remains: *Why is baseline alignment suppressed when the `.description` div has (block level) children?*

Comment: @Michael_B I was playing with `line-height` on the `h1` in the *inline-block demo in EDIT above* and I think that the baseline alignment is being done correclty... I give `vertical-align: top` to the empty div, it aligns vertically... let me know your thoughts...

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of using `visibility:hidden`, `visibility:hidden` only hides visibility of element, and element still acquires space, you should use `display:none;` rather than `visibility:hidden`

https://jsfiddle.net/67w721zq/1/

Comment: I want the effect of leaving the gap in the grid, because I return the item to its original position when the modal is closed. More than how to do it without the gap issue, I wan to know *why* this is happening

Comment: This answer doesn't provide an explanation, which is the main request in the question. It simply provides a workaround, that may not even meet the requirements of the layout.