# Why does changing the vertical alignment of one inline div only affect a separate inline div?

Tags: css

I have 3 identically sized inline divs with solid borders so they appear as rectangles.  I gave them classes of `left`, `center`, and `right`.

When I have the `left` class as `vertical-align: top` and the `right` class as `vertical-align: middle`, they appear like so:

[image]

If I add `vertical-align: bottom` to the `center` class, it doesn't affect the center block at all.  Rather, it moves the `right` class up as if I had made no `vertical-align` style rules at all.  What CSS rules are causing this?

[image]

[JSfiddle Before](http://jsfiddle.net/7kkC6/60/)

[JSfiddle After](http://jsfiddle.net/7kkC6/59/)

Comment: I would read [this article](http://christopheraue.net/2014/03/05/vertical-align/) to fully understand `vertical-align`. The main take away for me was this: _"Ok, technically, using vertical-align for layout is a hack, since it wasn’t invented for this reason. It’s there to align text and elements next to text."_

Comment: take a look at [this interesting question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39791663/mystery-space-created-above-row-when-removing-the-content-inside-of-one-item) that may give you more insights...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it is an interesting issue. I think the secret is by understanding that `vertical-align: middle` is different from the others, since it is affected by the lowercases letters of the parent element. I wrapped the divs in a wrapper in order to show it:

```css
.wrapper {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 120px;
  width: 500px;
}

div {
    display:inline-block;
    height:100px;
    width:25px;
    border:1px solid black;
}

.left{
  vertical-align: top;
}

.center{
}

.right{
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  sddsfsdfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsaa
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="center"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

So it's easy to see that the right div, with `vertical align: middle` is relative to the position of the lowercase letters.

As for the second example:

```css
.wrapper {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 120px;
  width: 500px;
}
div {
    display:inline-block;
    height:100px;
    width:25px;
    border:1px solid black;
}

.left{
  vertical-align: top;
}

.center{
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.right{
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  test test test test test
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="center"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Here everything works by the rules as well- the items are aligned according to the baseline, and the middle to the letters of the parent container.

You can find more details about this behaviour over [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/v/vertical-align/)